# Unable to run test assembly from Visual Studio Test on azure

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, unit-testing

I am trying to run my UnitTests on Azure. This is my YAML file for the Pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: 'Project.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: 'Project.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
          **\*test.dll
          !**\*TestAdapter.dll
          !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

All other steps run without any problem but the test assembly throw some errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\..\..\..\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@D:\a\_temp\n2ahdqizfd1.tmp"

vstest.console.exe 
"D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTestingAdapter.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll"
```

This means my references are recognized correctly.
And couple lines later:

```
Unable to load types from the test source 'D:\a\1\s\TEST_DWH_CORE\bin\Release\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered. 
Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And the error message is:

```
Initialization method TEST_DWH_CORE.table-to-test.TestInitialize threw exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found.
```

Comment: Are you using a PAAS database or a IAAS database and does the server have an IP address whitelist?

Comment: Also just to point out, your tests aren't really unit tests if they are connecting to a database. They would be classes as integration tests instead.

Comment: I develop a database locally and want to deploy it over azure to other servers. Actually the deployment works fine and the tables are deployed successfully on the destination server. I want to use azure as my test server so my tests which I wrote in VS are again run there.

Comment: Is it an Azure SQL Database or are you installing it on a VM?

Comment: This is a very good question which i have to answer in the next days before coming back to this issue. I am not sure if I have set up any database there.

Comment: Ok I've solved the problem somehow by myself. The tests run on the local DB of azure. The solution was to make publish files which contain localDB as destination for each project in the solution and push this publish file with other files into azure

Comment: @Amir Please post your solution as an answer below so it helps the rest of the community as well.